# A question about normal subgroups of nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Assume G is a nilpotent group and to any n dividing $|G|$, if there is always a normal subgroup of G with order n?

Comment: Yes that is correct! Since a finite nilpotent group is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, it is enough to prove it for finite $p$-groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of Derek Holt shows that it suffices to show it for $p$ -groups. Now to show it for $p$-groups you need to show that the center of a non-trivial $p$-group, is non-trivial and that it holds for abelian $p$-groups.

Then you show the property by induction. If $G$ is a non-abelian $p$-group then its center $Z$ is proper non-trivial. Take $p^k$ dividing $|G|$.

If $p^k\leq |Z|$ then you can find a subgroup of $Z$ of cardinal $p^k$. This subgroup is normal in $G$.

Else take a  normal subgroup of order $p^k/|Z|$ in $G/Z$ (by induction). I claim that the pull-back of this subgroup to $G$ will be normal in $G$ of order $p^k$.